# How to solve quest at Eldergleam sanctuary without casualties?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can I complete The Blessings of Nature without hurting the tree?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/36411/can-i-complete-the-blessings-of-nature-without-hurting-the-tree)

I reached the Eldergleam sanctuary in search of Eldergleam Sap for priestess Danica. Unfortunately as soon as I try to get if from elder tree some enemies spawn and kill all NPCs inside the sanctuary.

I am not strong enough to fight the enemies and I can only run out the sanctuary and leave them alone.

Is it possible solve the quest in pacifically without any casualties?

Comment: It is indeed a duplicated, sorry if I didn't find it first. I voted for close too.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can avoid a "diplomatic incident" with the Eldergleam tree by agreeing to escort the pilgrim who approaches you at the Whiterun temple. Bring him to the sanctuary, strike the tree roots (not the trunk) to climb the hill, and when you reach the trunk, he'll be horrified that you're planning on cutting the tree and offer you an alternative solution.

Comment: Ha!   So that's what that guy was good for.   Unfortunately he wasn't much good for fighting dragons.